# select based on specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table:

```
     ID     NO.
     111    6
     222    7
     333    9
     111    8
     333    4
     222    3
     111    7
     222    5
     333    2
```

I want to select only 2 ID numbers from table where NO. column equal specific values.
For example i tried this query but i didn't get the expected result:

```
SELECT top 2 * FROM mytable where NO. in 
(select NO. from mytable )
```

Expected result:

```
    111    6
    111    8
    222    7
    222    3
    333    9
```

333    3

Comment: So are you trying to get the two first values from the table for each `ID` value? What columns in your table define the order of the rows?

Comment: Additionally where did (333, 3)  come from in your expected result?

Comment: I'm a little surprised you have a period in the column name - that it's not treating it like you're attempting to specify a table (and thus throw an error).

Comment: You want the top 2 ID result but in the expected outcome you have more than 2 ID. It is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to select two rows in the table for each id, based on a condition on the `No` column.  For this, one method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from mytable t
      where <condition goes here>
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: yes It is something like that, random selection but limited to only two ID which are  based on specific values. I tried your query but I did get any rows.

Comment: @MalakNoor . . . If you didn't get any rows, it is because the inner `where` condition is filtering all of them out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing (333,3) is a mistake and you expect (333,2). If not I have no idea.

```
SELECT
    ua.ID
  , ua.[NO.]
FROM (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY t.[NO.] ASC) AS RowNum
  , t.ID
  , t.[NO.]
FROM dbo.t1 AS t
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY t.[NO.] DESC)
  , ID
  , t.[NO.]
FROM dbo.t1 AS t
) ua
WHERE ua.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY ID, ua.[NO.] DESC
```

If you're just trying to get top 2 values for each group, you need something to define the order, ie. a third column. Then you don't need UNION ALL, just use WHERE ua.RowNum < 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Select 2 random rows per id where the number of rows per id can vary between 1 and infinity
A good article for this:-*/
--https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3157/different-ways-to-get-random-data-for-sql-server-data-sampling/

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,NO INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES
(111,    6),
(222,    7),
(333 ,   9),
(111  ,  8),
(333   , 4),
(222   , 3),
(111   , 7),
(222   , 5),
(333   , 2)

select t.* from 
(
Select s.* ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY randomnumber) ROWNUMBER
from
(
 SELECT ID,NO, 
 (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100001) + ((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100001) * 0.00001) [randomnumber]
 FROM   @TABLE
) s 
) t
where t.rownumber < 3
```